# is there a format for the URL/hyperlink to source code for bitbucket server

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

is there a format for the URL/hyperlink to source code for bitbucket server
I searched through the BitBucket KB & Docs and I found one for BItBucket Cloud here: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/hyperlink-to-source-code-in-bitbucket/ & here: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/hyperlink-to-source-code-in-bitbucket/

However this does not work for BitBucket Server and I can't find one for BitBucket Server
My BitBucket Server version is 8.8.2